# How can I import pyside modules present in Lib/site-packages folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

I am new to python and desktop application. I am developing desktop application using pyside in windows.

I followed the steps as per the documentation in pyqt official site.

I am using python 2.7.8.
I have installed pyside using pip.
I have used following command:

```
pip install -U pyside
```

After Installation completes, pyside was in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`
folder.
But my python code is not able to see these modules due to which `import` fails.
I am getting error as :

```
ImportError: No module named pyside
```

Do I need to copy all these modules in `Script` folder where all other modules by default present.

I have checked `sys.path`. Output of sys.path is

```
['', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-12.0.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Pyt
hon27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Is there more configuration needed?
How can I import modules those are present in site-package folder?
Or any linking is required?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give the full error text you receive. So, start an interactive Python session, import sys and check sys.path, then just run `import pyside` and report what the results are. You do need to restart whatever Python sessions are running, such as those that may be running in your IDE, before newly-installed modules will show up. `site-packages` is their home, so you shouldn't have to move them anywhere.

Comment: I have updated error. Btw I have tried this in pycharm and sublime. I also created new session. But no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a silly error - the module is named `PySide` (with capital `P` and `S` letters), not `pyside`. Running

```
import PySide
```

should do the trick.

---

To figure this out, I used Sublime and a couple of cool plugins. I have [`IPython`](http://www.ipython.org) and all its dependencies installed, mainly from [Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython) repository. I use [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) with its IPython extension to run IPython within Sublime (I use ST3, which I highly recommend). I also have the excellent [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) plugin installed, which provides great Python autocompletion along with linting (which I don't use). Once you've set up your environment or project file to point to your desired version of Python, it will autocomplete module, method, and attribute names for you in `.py` files as well as in SublimeREPL. So, I just typed `import pyside` and the only available option was `PySide`.

This could also be determined by looking at the folder's name within your `site-packages` directory, as they are case-sensitive.